# can I use orderBychild("person").limitToLast(1) to get the last record which has the property "person"?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

My application sends the messages which have variable properties to firebase database.

some messages only have 2 properties:

```
{
  "time": "xxxx"
  "location": "xxxxxx"
}
```

others have 3 properties:

```
{
  "time": "xxxx"
  "location": "xxxxxx"
  "person": "xxxx"
}
```

The messages are sent without a specific order. 
I want to get the last message which has the property "person", my javascript code is like:

```
    fireBaseRef.orderByChild("person").limitToLast(1).once("value").then((snapshot)=> {
        var temp = snapshot.val();
        for (var tempkey in temp) {
             console.log("person is:" + temp[tempkey].person;
        }
    })
```

Is my code correct? I did some tests, it doesn't work well.